# How can I make the navigation bar on my iPhone app look metallic?

Tags: iphone, ios

I don't know how my client mocked up their screenshots, but they ended up with an image where the navigation bar has a kind of two-tone metallic look, like this:

[image: Metallic.]

But when I build the app, it ends up fading gradually from my tint colour towards white, like this:

[image: Not so metallic.]

The trouble is, the clients really like the way it looks in their mock-up.  What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclass `UINavigationBar`. In your subclass, override `drawRect:` to custom-draw what you want. In your instance of `UINavigationController`, make sure the navigation bar is an instance of your subclass.

If you're programmatically instantiating your navigation controller, you might not be able to do this--you may have to resort to adding a category to `UINavigationBar` that overrides drawing for all instances:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomDrawing)
- (void)drawRect: (CGRect)rect {
    // ...
}
@end
```

It's also possible to use method swizzling to override `UINavigationBar`'s default behaviour, but explaining method swizzling is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: That's what we've gone with.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

On the heels of @Jonathan's answer [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2079/core-graphics-101-shadows-and-gloss) has a great tutorial on creating your own gradients.

Here's a snippit:

```
void drawGlossAndGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor, 
    CGColorRef endColor) {

    drawLinearGradient(context, rect, startColor, endColor);

    CGColorRef glossColor1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 
        blue:1.0 alpha:0.35].CGColor;
    CGColorRef glossColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 
        blue:1.0 alpha:0.1].CGColor;

    CGRect topHalf = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, 
        rect.size.width, rect.size.height/2);

    drawLinearGradient(context, topHalf, glossColor1, glossColor2);

}
```

Comment: @Tommy, yes he is.  Local to me too.  I go to his site for pretty much everything I need to learn.  Can't wait till his book is out.